# Pandas pivot table - mean value with condition

Tags: pandas

I have this `pivot_table`:

```
                                        sum       mean
                                 pontos_num pontos_num
clube        opponent home_dummy                      
Athlético-PR 263      1               29.35   1.834375
             265      1               59.78   3.516471
             266      1                9.16   0.538824
             267      0               15.93   0.937059
             275      1               -7.31  -0.430000
```

---

How can I get a mean value for the column `points_num` under `sum` level, only if `home_dummy == 1`?

---

EDIT:

`df.columns`

```
MultiIndex([( 'sum', 'pontos_num'),
            ('mean', 'pontos_num')],
           )
```

Comment: Can you do `df.columns` and paste the column names here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name for a multi-index column is a tuple, which you can call.

To filter `home_dummy` on the index, you can use `.query()`:

```
df.query('home_dummy == 1')[('sum', 'pontos_num')].mean()
```